# Python split a string by delimiter and trim all elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, split, delimiter

Is there a Python lambda code available to split the following string by the delimiter ">" and create the list after trimming each element?

Input: `"p1 > p2 > p3 > 0"`

Output: `["p1", "p2", "p3", "0"]`

Comment: Just `str.split(" > ")` ?

Comment: `list(map(str.strip, s.split(">")))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with the comment that all you need is:

```
>>> "p1 > p2 > p3 > 0".split(" > ")
['p1', 'p2', 'p3', '0']
```

However, if the whitespace is inconsistent and you need to do exactly what you said (split then trim) then you could use a [list comprehension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_comprehension#Python)  like:

```
>>> s = "p1 > p2 > p3 > 0"
>>> [x.strip() for x in s.split(">")]
['p1', 'p2', 'p3', '0']
```